# UITableview on a vertical ScrollView

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ios6

I have a vertical `UIScrollView` it's having 3 different `viewControllers` and on third `view controller` I have a table view.

when I scroll my `UIScrollview` to third page then table view comes and table view is getting scrolled but i am not able to scroll up to my second page.

how can I handle both the scrolls and scroll back to my second page of `UIScrollView`.

Means both the scrolling enabled at the same time

Comment: u want ur table to scroll or not?

Comment: I need both to be scrollable

Comment: then decrease ur table's width so that they can touch scrollview to scroll it.

Comment: I shifted my table views y 20 pixels down and it works but i also need if my table view over scrolls (top cells are visible and i continue dragging the table view down) the upper scroll gets enabeled

Comment: if my table view is bouncing then i need my scroll view gets activate and my second page of scroll view gets loaded

Comment: `- (void)scrollViewWillBeginDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView willDecelerate:(BOOL)decelerate` Use these to detect top bouncing. Keep a counter, and after the counter expires you can programmatically send scroll event to your scrollview.

Answer (score 0):

i think you can set your scrollview's postion alway display in your screen(eg.when the tableview is display of 3/4 in screen,forbid scrollview is scroll to top,and the scrollview can be scrolling to down),and the tableview is a part of screen,i hope it help you.

Sorry,My English is very poor(lol).

Answer (score 0):

UITableview inside UIScrollview is not a preferred way by apple that can cause unpredictable results .I will say you to reconsider the design of the app.

One thing you can do is to disable the scroll of tableview make its frame to the height of the whole table height to view and add it as a subview to the scrollview,so that the table whole content is visible and the scroll will be managed by the scrollview itself.